# creating an aspect for spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm having a problem (as well as many other people it seems) with spring data elasticsearch ignoring the field name specified by @JsonProperty. There's a lot of discussions going on whether this be supported or not.

I thought, for now, the best way to overcome this is to create an aspect around the internal implementation of the spring data elasticsearch and change the searched field name myself before returning to the method, i was wondering if this is doable, if so, i would very much appreciate a sample code or some guidelines.